# How to delete AWS ECS repositories which contain images using Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-ecs

I want to delete an AWS ECS repository using Ansible.
My Ansible version is 2.4.1.0 and it "should" support this as you can lookup here: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/ecs_ecr_module

However it doesn't work as intended because my repository still contains docker images.

Here's the code snippet:

```
- name: destroy-ecr-repos
  ecs_ecr: name=jenkins-app state=absent
```

The resulting error message is:

```
... 
The error was: RepositoryNotEmptyException: An error occurred (RepositoryNotEmptyException) when calling the DeleteRepository operation: The repository with name 'jenkins-app' in registry with id 'xyz' cannot be deleted because it still contains images 
...
```

In the AWS Console it works perfectly fine. There's just a warning text which reminds you that there are still images left in the repository. But you're still able to force the deletion.

And now my question(s):
Is it somehow possible to force the deletion of the repository including its images?
... OR ...
Can I delete them with another tool separately before deleting the repository?

Maybe there simply is no implementation from the ansible side and I have to use the 'shell' module instead (and maybe open a feature request for that).

I'm very grateful for any advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First things first: Thanks to @vikas027
Solution from his/her/its answer: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/delete-repository.html#examples

History:

Ok, now I figured out, that there currently is no ansible functionality which supports the implicit deletion of images when deleting repositories on ecs.

BUT
I've implemented a workaround that despite its ugliness works for me.
I simply delete the image per shell module using the aws cli before actually removing the ecs repo.

Here's the snippet to do so:

```
- name: Delete remaining images in our repositories
  shell: |
    aws ecr list-images --repository-name jenkins-app --query 'imageIds[*]' --output text | while read imageId; do aws ecr batch-delete-image --repository-name jenkins-app --image-ids imageDigest=$imageId; done

- name: destroy-ecr-repo jenkins-app
  ecs_ecr: name=jenkins-app state=absent
```

Hope that helps someone who faces this issue before ansible implements a possibility to delete images via built-in module.

Comment: AWS cli now supports force deletion of ECR repositories `$ aws ecr delete-repository --repository-name <repo_name> --force` . [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/delete-repository.html#examples) is the updated doco.

Comment: @vikas027 thank you very much for this update. I'll add this to my self-accepted ;-) answer.

Comment: The query `imageIds[*]` returns both image digests and tags, leading to some errors. `imageIds[*].imageDigest` selects just the digests.